# Problema al usar credential client auth0

Tags: auth0

Estoy teniendo problemas al querer obtener un token.
Alguien puede ayudarme? Está bien la url, los parametros??

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! muchos problemas aca.. primero lo que tachaste, se ve todo, asi que ya tenes que dar de baja esas dos cosas.. YA... no podemos hacer que desaparezca por desgracia... avisa a la gente que corresponde, que filtraste esa informacion... y luego, no se los grant_types, pero dice que ese no es valido...